# Bitwise operators in C

Tags: c

I'm doing a project which is relevant to beautification code.Actually this programm i'm supposed to write is in C and works in same way as pretty print or index(if you're heard about them).My question is:I 've searched through the internet and found a similar code to my project but it uses bitwise operators.In which way can i modify my programm so not to use this operators?This is a code that i found through the internet..I hope someone can help me and tell me how can i get rid of these operators and instead write a code without them.Thanks a lot!

```
#define FLAG_PRINT          ( 1 << 0 )
#define FLAG_NEWLINE        ( 1 << 1 )
#define FLAG_TABS           ( 1 << 2 )

void print_tabs(int count)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    putchar('\t');
}

int main()
{
int ch;
int fflags = 0;
int lflags = 0;
int tab = 0;
while ( (ch = getchar()) != EOF )
{
    //////////////// flag setting
    switch(ch)
    {
    case ';':
        fflags |= FLAG_PRINT;
        lflags |= FLAG_NEWLINE | FLAG_TABS;
        break;
    case '{':
        fflags |= 0 ;
        lflags |= FLAG_NEWLINE | FLAG_TABS | FLAG_PRINT;
        tab++;

        break;
    case '}':
        fflags |= FLAG_NEWLINE | FLAG_TABS;
        lflags |= FLAG_NEWLINE | FLAG_TABS | FLAG_PRINT;
        tab--;
        break;
    case ' ':
        fflags |= FLAG_PRINT;
        break;
    default:
        if(!isspace(ch))
            fflags |= FLAG_PRINT;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    /// first order flags
    if(fflags & FLAG_PRINT)
        putchar(ch);
    if(fflags & FLAG_NEWLINE)
        putchar('\n');
    if(fflags & FLAG_TABS)
        print_tabs(tab);

    // last order flags
    if(lflags & FLAG_PRINT)
        putchar(ch);
    if(lflags & FLAG_NEWLINE)
        putchar('\n');
    if(lflags & FLAG_TABS)
        print_tabs(tab);

    //reset
    fflags = 0;
    lflags = 0;
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with bitwise operators?

Comment: That the project must not use bitwise operators,only int variables

Comment: That seems like an odd requirement. Is this a homework question? It's okay if it is, but you need to show us what work you've put into so far, besides just finding a code sample you want to modify.

Comment: Uhm... your comment makes no sense @Vkt678. You might as well be telling us: "I can't use a spoon while making soup. I can only use tomatoes!"

Comment: By the way, hint: `1|2 = 1+2` and `2|4 = 2+4` but `2|3 != 2+3`

Comment: Yeah actually it's a homework that a professor from the university gave me.Look this exercise requires so many things,but in general what i supposed to do is to write a programm in which when i give  in input a programm which is "not writen  beautiful" and the output will be the same programm beautified.I've statred to write code but i had problem,so i found that code that does " in about 80%" the same work.I say in about 80% because it hasn't some cases but if i try to modify and work on dat,i can surely expand and cover all tha cases from the programm in input.(Sorry for the long post)

Comment: For every `FLAG_XXX` declare an int variable `int flag_XXX;`. Instead of writing `fflags |= FLAG_XXX` write `flag_XXX = 1;` and instead of `fflags = 0;` write one `flag_XXX = 0;` for every possible XXX. And replace `if (fflags & FLAG_XXX)` by `if (flag_XXX)`.

Answer (score 3):

If all values are distinct single bits (so you never get carry), you can use '+' to achieve the effect of '|'.

Shift can be replaced by multiplication/division by powers of two.

Some of the other operators are harder to replace while still doing bitwise operations. You may be able to precompute, or implement your own functions using table lookup, or you might want to use something like an array rather than bit flags within an int.

But the real-world answer is that bitwise operations exist for good reasons, and it's foolish not to use them when you need them.

Comment: The reason that i will not use bitwise operations is because in the university the professor did not tell anything about them.So how am i supposed to use them?

Comment: Perhaps be reading a C manual, so you know about:  '<<'(left shift), '>>'(right shift), '&'(and) '|'(or).  I would expect you learned about boolean logic back in high school during your algebra class so it should be simple to learn how to use that logic in C.

Comment: Yeah you have a point there.For example can you explain me what does this command do? lflags |= FLAG_NEWLINE | FLAG_TABS | FLAG_PRINT;

Comment: Read The Fine Manual. There are LOTS of C tutorials out there.

Comment: If i understood right this command do: Ifflags=Ifflags+FLAG_NEWLINE+FLAG_TABS+FLAG_PRINT...

Answer (score 0):

Here are int values that are the same as the #defines at the top of the program. However, the #defines are usable with more data types than the const int values

```
#define FLAG_PRINT          ( 1 << 0 )
#define FLAG_NEWLINE        ( 1 << 1 )
#define FLAG_TABS           ( 1 << 2 )
```

can also be written as:

```
const int FLAG_PRINT   = 0x01;
const int FLAG_NEWLINE = 0x02;
const int FLAG_TABS    = 0x04;

suggest, for good programing practice,
changing the names to something like:
flagPrint
flagNewline
flagTabs
```

Answer (score 0):

Although using bits seems like the best way to do it, if you insist on not using bits, you can do it with bitfields like this:

```c
typedef union Flags {
    unsigned int allFlags;
    struct {
        unsigned int print   : 1;
        unsigned int newline : 1;
        unsigned int tabs    : 1;
    };
} Flags;

Flags fflags = {0};

// To set flags:
fflags.print   = 1;
fflags.newline = 1;

// To test a flag:
if (fflags.print) {
}

// To clear all flags:
fflags.allFlags = 0;
```

If you don't know anything about bitfields or unions, then do the completely simple way like this:

```c
typedef struct Flags {
    int print;
    int newline;
    int tabs;
} Flags;

Flags fflags = {0};

// To set flags:
fflags.print   = 1;
fflags.newline = 1;

// To test a flag:
if (fflags.print) {
}

// To clear all flags:
memset(&fflags, 0, sizeof(fflags));

// Or if you never used memset:
fflags.print   = 0;
fflags.newline = 0;
fflags.tabs    = 0;
```

Comment: Wait a minute,this is similar with the first one?Where's the switch  and the if's ?

Comment: I didn't copy any of your code, I was just showing you how to do it another way.  You will have to modify your code yourself.